# Is there a way to compose two matrix of numbers in one matrix of text?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I would like to compose two matrix of numbers into one matrix of formated text in python.

Is there a easy way?

I could use `for`, but I just want this because is better for work.

As a simple example:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])

array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

to

```
array([['0:0', '1:0', '2:0'],
       ['0:1', '1:1', '2:1'],
       ['0:2', '1:2', '2:2'],
       ['0:3', '1:3', '2:3'],
       ['0:4', '1:4', '2:4']])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.dstack to combine both the arrays and use string manipulation with comprehension to manipulate each cell of the combined array

```
>>> arr = np.dstack((arr1, arr2))
>>> np.array([np.array([':'.join(map(str,cell)) for cell in row ]) for row in arr])
array([['0:0', '1:0', '2:0'],
       ['0:1', '1:1', '2:1'],
       ['0:2', '1:2', '2:2'],
       ['0:3', '1:3', '2:3'],
       ['0:4', '1:4', '2:4']], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [nditer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html) to iterate over the arrays, and make strings as needed: e.g.

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])

a2 = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])

out=np.empty(a1.shape, dtype='S5')

for x,y,o in np.nditer([a1, a2, out], op_flags=['readwrite']):
    o[...] = "{}:{}".format(x,y)


print(out)
```

Result:

```
[['0:0' '1:0' '2:0']
 ['0:1' '1:1' '2:1']
 ['0:2' '1:2' '2:2']
 ['0:3' '1:3' '2:3']
 ['0:4' '1:4' '2:4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehensions and zip() to form a new array:

```
from numpy import array

ar1 = array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])

ar2 = array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])

res = array([['%s:%s' % (j1, j2) for j1, j2 in zip(i1, i2)] for i1, i2 in zip(ar1, ar2)])
print(res)
```

Result:

```
[['0:0' '1:0' '2:0']
 ['0:1' '1:1' '2:1']
 ['0:2' '1:2' '2:2']
 ['0:3' '1:3' '2:3']
 ['0:4' '1:4' '2:4']]
```

This solution will also fit usual Python two-dimensional lists (just remove the 'array' functions).